# Why can i change elements in "inspect element" but the same changes in my css file do not make a difference?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, jsx

I'm attempting to change the padding on a JSX element. In inspect element, i can change the padding easily, but when i try the same thing in the CSS file, nothing changes.

1. The css file is linked correctly, this is the first element i've had this issue with after probably 20 on the same file that worked fine.
2. I've cleared the cache on my browser.
3. Parent elements have necessary settings, such as height and width.

I'm likely just missing something, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i had to include !important after the css line to override what it wanted to do.

example...

```
  .topLine {
      padding-right: 5% !important;
   }
```